# How to deploy application on https server

Tags: java, maven, weblogic

I have application which I am deploying on http server using maven. Here everything works. Now I need to deploy this application on https server. I am trying using this:

```
mvn clean install weblogic:deploy -Dmaven.test.skip=true  -P profil -Dwls-userId=user -Dwls-password=pass -Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=CustomTrust -Dweblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStoreType=JKS -Dweblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStoreFileName=path/to/cert.jks -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true -Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true -Dweblogic.security.SSL.enableJSSE=true
```

but I got exception:

```
javax.enterprise.deploy.spi.exceptions.DeploymentManagerCreationException: [J2EE Deployment SPI:260009]Exception caught for class 'weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.internal.ServerConnectionImpl' while attempting to create DeploymentManager: java.nio.channels.IllegalBlockingModeException
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.<init>(WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.java:130)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.factories.internal.DeploymentFactoryImpl.getDeploymentManager(DeploymentFactoryImpl.java:86)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.getRemoteDeploymentManager(SessionHelper.java:496)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Jsr88Operation.connect(Jsr88Operation.java:297)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Deployer.perform(Deployer.java:137)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Deployer.runBody(Deployer.java:88)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:158)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:115)
    at weblogic.Deployer.run(Deployer.java:70)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.weblogic.DeployMojoBase.executeDeployer(DeployMojoBase.java:514)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.weblogic.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:49)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.IllegalBlockingModeException
    at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaChannelInputStream.read(JaChannelInputStream.java:43)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readLine(DataInputStream.java:513)
    at weblogic.rjvm.t3.MuxableSocketT3.connect(MuxableSocketT3.java:401)
    at weblogic.rjvm.t3.ConnectionFactoryT3S.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryT3S.java:40)
    at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.createConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1777)
    at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.findOrCreateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1417)
    at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:437)
    at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:315)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreateRemoteInternal(RJVMManager.java:254)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreate(RJVMManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateRemoteServer(RJVMFinder.java:238)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateInternal(RJVMFinder.java:200)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreate(RJVMFinder.java:170)
    at weblogic.rjvm.ServerURL.findOrCreateRJVM(ServerURL.java:153)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate$1.run(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:345)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:147)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:340)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:315)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:285)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.createInitialContext(Environment.java:208)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getInitialContext(Environment.java:192)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getInitialContext(Environment.java:170)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.internal.ServerConnectionImpl.getContext(ServerConnectionImpl.java:328)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.internal.ServerConnectionImpl.getEnvironment(ServerConnectionImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.internal.ServerConnectionImpl.init(ServerConnectionImpl.java:139)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.getNewConnection(WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.java:148)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.<init>(WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.java:118)
```

and error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:3.9.3:deploy (default-cli) on project app: Exception encountered during artifact start: weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.DeployerException: Unable to connect to 't3s://10.143.3.16:7012': null. Ensure the url represents a running admin server and that the credentials are correct. If using http protocol, tunneling must be enabled on the admin server. [J2EE Deployment SPI:260009]Exception caught for class 'weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.internal.ServerConnectionImpl' while attempting to create DeploymentManager: java.nio.channels.IllegalBlockingModeException -> [Help 1]
```

can you help me how to fix it ?

Comment: Obviously you have checked that the url is correct and that there is an admin server running and that the credentials are correct ;)

Comment: yes url is correct admin server is running. And what you mean with credentials. How I can check it ?

Comment: credentials are username and password which you appear to be passing in on your command line as '-Dwls-userId=user -Dwls-password=pass'

Comment: yes this is correct too. I can login to admin console

Comment: have imported the ssl certificate of this server in the keystore? most of java application refuses to open an ssl connection the remote endpoint certificate is not in the trusted keystore.